# Will the gnome-classic session be available in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, session, 18.04

With Ubuntu 18.04, I know that there will be the default Ubuntu GNOME session, and that you'll be able to install a separate GNOME session which will take away the Ubuntu shell customizations.

Will there also be a GNOME Classic session (with both a top and bottom bar, the date / time items on the right of the screen, etc.).  This session is something that you can select in Fedora, but I'm not sure if it will be available in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Questions about what software may or may not be in future Ubuntu releases are off topic. The flashback session will still not be installed by default however, but it will be available to install from the archives, just as it is in 16.04 and 17.10.

Comment: Both packages [`gnome-session-flashback`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-session-flashback) and [`gnome-panel`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gnome-panel&searchon=names) are available in 18.04 LTS.